# What does the language of DFA of LR itemsets represent?

Tags: finite-automata, context-free, compilers

As we know, if we want to make a $LR(0)$ (say) parsing table for a context free grammar (CFG), we prepare the $LR(0)$ itemsets with $.$ (dot) in RHS of the CFG production.

With this $.$ we keep track of characters that compiler has seen yet, and continue to make states of these itemsets, which ultimately make a deterministic finite machine (DFA).

Formation of DFA is natural, as the compiler will visit the *finite* states *deterministically*.

My question is, **what does the regular language of this DFA signify?**

Answer (score 1):

For grammar
$$
S \rightarrow Sa | b
$$
The following represents the $LR(0)$ itemset and its finite automata. *(ignore the $ symbol)*
[image: FA of LR0 Itemsets]

If every state is final state of the above $FA$, it would recognise $\{\epsilon, b, S, Sa \}$ , hence this is set of all **viable prefixes**, which are defined as *the prefixes of right sentential forms that can
appear on the stack of a shift-reduce parser.*